# JMS Queue with 2 Listeners

Tags: java, jms, jms-topic

I have a question as regards JMS Queues.

I have implemented a jms sender/reciever using a shared queue as its the only queue avaialbe to me and the only one i can use.

The problem that i am now faced with is that i as this first come first served i cannot guarentee that the messages that i am sending from my producer will be consumed by my consumer and not the other sharing this queue and vice versa. So i am consuming the other apps messages and they are consuming mine.

Is there a way i can just listen for my messages and not consume them from the queue or is this more of a topic implementation?

Or perhaps i can explicitly set an identifier that only my consumer will pick up.

My main code:

```
public class AsyncReceiver implements MessageListener, ExceptionListener
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{                                                                          
    //create queue factory
        factory = new TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
        //create queue connection
        queueConn = factory.createQueueConnection(userName, password);
        queueConn.setExceptionListener(this);
        //create queue session
        session = queueConn.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        //receive message by QueueReceiver
        final Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
        final QueueReceiver queueReceiver = session.createReceiver(queue);
        queueReceiver.setMessageListener(this);
        queueConn.start  ();                                                                      
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use JMS selector. Every JMS message can contain properties that you initiate at sender's side.

Message consumer can register to JMS destination (either queue or topic) specifying selector - SQL-like statement that explains which messages does it want to consume. So you can specify your application specific property and then receive relevant messages only.

Comment: Thanks @AlexR for your response, would you have an example of how i might do this? Is this set in the Message itself and not necessarily the connection for the sender? On the reciever the selector is specified in the creation of the QueuReciever? `final QueueReceiver queueReceiver = session.createReceiver(queue, "JMS_SELECTOR");`

Answer (score 1):

You could use message selector as shown below

queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(responseQueue, "JMSCorrelationID='" 
                    + requestMessage.getJMSCorrelationID() +"'");

Here i am using the JMS correlation ID to identify the correct message I need. 
Please note that the filter will only work on Message Header and Message properties. 
It will not work on the message content.

Details on Message Header & Properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS4.html#wp79367

If you need to filter based on message content, you may have to use QueueSession.MANUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE mode and acknowledge messages that you want. In this case the application has to have the logic to identify messages based on content. Not the ideal design though.

Comment: Thanks @ SMS Krishnan, as regards you example how do you know requestMessage.getJMSCorrelationID() when this is really part of the initalisation? Do you do anyting on the publisher side to set this?